# Global exception handling in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, error-handling, struts2, xml-configuration

How can I implement a global exception handler for Apache Struts 2?

I'm using annotations (with struts.property) and NOT `struts.xml`.

I have got it to work for action-classes (at class and method level) but I would like something more global like a stand-alone class.

Can I for example use the `ExeptionHandler` from Struts 2? Hard to find documentation and examples.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map exceptions to result that calls the action that would handle the exception.

```xml
<global-results>
    <result name="exception" type="chain">
        <param name="actionName">exceptionHandler</param>
        <param name="namespace">/</param>
    </result>
</global-results>
<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="exception" />
</global-exception-mappings>
```

**References:**

- [Exception Configuration](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/exception-configuration.html)
- [Result Configuration](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/result-configuration.html)

Comment: But shouldn't that be placed inside struts.xml? The project I'm working on doesn't use the struts.xml (doesn't exist), it uses annotations.

Comment: @Staplerz annotations is an additional feature integrated with Struts2, it *doesn't* replace xml configuration.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm new to struts2...
I've found that there is an ExceptionHandler class in struts2 that could be defined in the struts.xml file as an <global-exeptions> element as according to following example: http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-global-custom-exception-example/ This is more like what I'm looking for. However I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: There's not `ExceptionHandler` class in Struts2, you can use `exception` interceptor with global exception mappings. The example is for Struts1.3.x, and it's a different framework than Struts2.

Comment: Oh, it seems that it's part of struts 1. I will try your solution. Thanks!